# YouTube Data API limit reached! How can I increase this limit?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My application uses the YouTube Data API v3 and every day I hit a limit of 10k query cost at which point my application is unusable.

I understand the old default limit was 1m (100x!) and I can find NO way to increase it. I completed the google form titled "YouTube Data API Services – Exceptions form" which is apparently the only line of contact according to cloud support and have not received any update in over two weeks. Is there ANY other way to increase it?

I had no idea google API would be the largest hurdle in my project. thanks! :)

Comment: there isnt much you can do you need to wait for them to extend it.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129900545 Correction you can post a rant to their issue forum